# How to perform Fisher exact test in SPSS?

Tags: spss, contingency-tables

I've  collected around 10 numbers of  ants from a colony and introduced the same numbers of ants to the same  colony (say Colony-1) at their entrance to see their behaviour (whether they accepts or rejects). Again I introduced 10 ants from different colony (say Colony-2, i.e. non-nestmate) to Colony-1 and checked their rate of  acceptance and rejectance. Likewise I introduced another 10 ants from another colony (say colony-3) to colony-1 to see the same.
The data I got looks like that:

```
                 *In Colony-1*
    Accepted         Rejected      Colony
     8                  2         Colony-1
     3                  7         Colony-2
     2                  8         Colony-3
```

Now my question is that how I should arrange these data in SPSS 11.5 and run Fischer exact test in order to get the P-value and percentage of acceptance and rejection in Colony-1?

Comment: The first Google hit for [spss fisher exact test](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/whatstat/whatstat.htm) says you need the "SPSS Exact Test Module".